# Merge two SELECT statements and return one JSON response

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to merge the results of two select statements and return one single JSON response. Basically, I want to return id, name, company, and email for every record found, but also return the signature column if the ticket matches the POST data.

Also, is it possible to remove any duplicate records in the final array?

```
$selectTable = "tickets_info";
$selectColumns = "id, name, company, email";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $selectColumns FROM $selectTable WHERE created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute();

if (isset($_POST['ticket'])) {

    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT signature FROM tickets_info WHERE ticket = ?");
    $stmt2->execute(array($_POST['ticket']));

}

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (isset($_POST['ticket'])) {

    $results = $stmt2->fetchAll();

}

if ($results) {

    header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
    echo json_encode($results);

}
```

Comment: Where is `$_POST['ticket']` coming from?

Comment: Being posted from an ajax request

Comment: I would do one `SELECT` including `signature` in the first place. How would the result of this look different to the intended result? Can you edit your question to include an example of the desired json, please?

Comment: The signature field contains a large amount of data that I don't want returned for every result. To save on bandwidth I would prefer if signature is included only when specifically needed.

Comment: Is `signature` column unique?

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the query response with something along these lines:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, company, email, signature, ticket FROM tickets_info WHERE created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute() ;
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $response[$i]['id'] = $row['id'] ;
  $response[$i]['name'] = $row['name'] ;
  $response[$i]['company'] = $row['company'] ;
  $response[$i]['email'] = $row['email'] ;

  if ($row['ticket'] == $_POST['ticket']) $response[$i]['signature'] = $row['signature'] ;
  else $response[$i]['signature'] = NULL ;

  $i++ ;
}

header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
echo json_encode($response);
```

You only do one SQL query and loop through the response once. If that row matches the AJAX ticket query, we add the signature to the array of objects. If not, we set the signature value to `null`.

Answer (score -1):

The right way to do is use [Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) . If you don't want to do it with join you can first put the results in two different arrays. then [merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) those two seperate arrays and then [filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) any duplicate arrays.

Remember you want to have the same keys for both Sql Queries.

Comment: I'm not sure a `JOIN` is what's needed here. There is only one table.

Comment: i would say use while loop to put the results in array and then use merge and array_unique. but i like to say if the quantity is high it may impact your performance